# ExpressJS Node Process won't end "normally"

Tags: node.js, express

NodeJS v 16.15.1 Windows 10.

Since a few days, neither nodemon nor VSCode can end node processes which use `app.listen()` of express. When the code changes we see:

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
```

But nothing happens after that. We have to kill the processes manually in task manager.

```js
'use strict';
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = 8040;
// The PROBLEMATIC line:
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Started on http://localhost:${PORT} (PID: ${process.pid})`);
});
```

If I remove "The PROBLEMATIC line" then nodemon/vscode can restart the process.

There is NO error message, the app just does not exit. For example by entering `rs`:
[image]

Nothing happens, no matter how long I wait.

Using `nodemon --signal SIGTERM` makes no difference, the process never sees the SIGTERM.

Using the package `why-is-node-running` we see:

```
There are 5 handle(s) keeping the process running

# TCPSERVERWRAP
C:\services\overview\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:635 - return server.listen.apply(server, arguments);
C:\services\overview\src\tmp2.js:6                               - app.listen(PORT, () => {

# TTYWRAP
C:\services\overview\src\tmp2.js:7 - console.log(`Started on http://localhost:${PORT} (PID: ${process.pid})`);

# HTTPINCOMINGMESSAGE
(unknown stack trace)

# HTTPINCOMINGMESSAGE
(unknown stack trace)

# TickObject
(unknown stack trace)
```

Comment: Since you seem to be starting `nodemon` from a terminal provided by VS Code, have you tried to see what happens if you start it from a regular terminal (not sure what it's called in Windows, `cmd`?).

Comment: Same issue when using a normal terminal and not vs code.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue (although I'm using macOS and `nodemon@2.0.16`).

Comment: People next to me with the same PC and code also can't reproduce the issue. It's definitely a PC/user error. `node_modules` deleted and `npm ci` have been tried. NPM cache clear etc.

Comment: Reinstalled OS, doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You want end the node/nodemon process? Why not using ctrl + c instead

Comment: Nodemon automatically restarts the node process when code changes. This makes it easy to develop new features without manually starting node with ctrl+c. Yes, I can stop my process with ctrl+c but I have to restart it manually so it's not ideal.